# Blender Cloud Login For 2.91

Tags: blender-id

I just bought Blender cloud, and I'm trying to find how to login. I saw that there is an addon but I was unable to find it. Is the Login Addon supposed to be included in blender cloud addon?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/system/blender_id.html
System: Blender ID authentication addon.

Search for ID in search and you will find it.

This is a doc loop that is unclear - a ticket should be put in place to mention that the addon referenced is an addon and not a website.
tickets can probably be put in to https://github.com/dfelinto/blender-cloud-addon

Answer (score 0):

The [Blender ID Authentication](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/system/blender_id.html#blender-id-authentication) add-on is bundled with blender, and can be enabled from user preferences.

[image]

---

You login with the same [*Blender Id*](https://id.blender.org/login) that you created when you joined Blender Cloud.
This is the same authentication that you use on cloud as well as the tracker.